# how can I print a parameter with special characters

Tags: batch-file

I'm just beginning to learn batch script and I want to take a string parameter with special characters and print it out but it removes them from the string and there's no explanation for this online

for example :

```
DFS**%2DSQS^2$^!2@=+
```

it prints out

```
DFS**%2DSQS2$!2@
```

here is the code

```
@echo off
echo %1 
set message=%~1
echo %message%
```

What do I do?

Comment: For an answer, it's necessary to know how you process/store the parameter into a variable. Please show the code

Comment: We need to know how you're passing that string to the batch file, but generally it needs to be passed within double-quotes, `"DFS**%2DSQS^2$^!2@=+"`, then you would expand it in the batch file, `%~1`, to remove those enclosing double-quotes. e.g. `echo %~1`, and `set "message=%~1"`. But please note that some of those characters are poison characters within a batch file, so would need to be escaped, or a workaround used to print them.

Comment: You are not really just printing the variable to the console. So you should expand your question, to show us what you are really doing with that input, so that we can suggest the most robust or efficient escaping/workaround method.